# getting return type dictionary from external C# method call

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping

I am using XSLT for calling a C# method that in turn calls an Oracle database and returns a set of Key Values in a Dictionary.
I need this Dictionary stored in a variable in my xslt and then pass it on as a parameter to another external C# function.
Although if I define the C# function in the `<msxsl:script>` section , it gives me a design time error.
Any ideas on how to do it. Do I need to refer to an additional namespace in the xslt?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete C# and XSLT snippets to reproduce the problem, together with precise information of the XSLT processor you are using that with.

Comment: I eventually managed to work it out by changing the C# method to return the values in form of an Xml instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
I managed to work out the problem by changing the data type of my C# method from a Dictionary to a Xml instead.
According to this link (**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-stylesheet-scripting-using-msxsl-script**)
the arguments and Return types for any of the scripts being called from XSLT should be one of these:

System.String   
System.Boolean  
System.Double   
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator     
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator  

Hope this helps!
```